# Silverlight problem with OS X Lion

Tags: silverlight, osx-lion

If by chance Someone will input "⌘" symbol in any **Silverlight** application under **OS X Lion** the application will crash.
This is really very strange issue and any ideas on overcoming this (like changing some configurations in OS X) will be appreciated.
This is happening under **Firefox/Safari** didn't install **Chrome** yet.

**UPDATE:**
Input means pasting "⌘" symbol **not** pressing **command key**.
Even having TextBlock which contains "⌘" symbol will make Silverlight crash.

Comment: What do you mean if they "input" it? Do you mean if a user hits that key while your app has focus? Or do you mean that they paste that into some control in your app?

Comment: Seems was I was not clear. 
If you past that symbol.I'll update question soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution that I could figure out is to use image of ⌘ symbol instead of original symbol.
This is not what I was looking for , but seems to be the only solution so far.
This solution wont help with TextBox, in case of TextBox whenever user input ⌘ symbol application will crash.